# Have a problem two components data binding

Tags: angular

I have a problem with data binding two components. The first one sends the data as an object and the second one iterates over it and outputs the data in inputs (value is the value of every element). I want to change the values of the object in the first component when the values of the inputs change.

FIRST COMPONENT

```
 test: any;

 this.test= await this.authService.getMultilingual('en'); - ts

<form >
  <app-iteration-multilingual *ngIf="test" [(array)] = 'test'></app-iteration-multilingual>
</form>
```

---

SECOND COMPONENT

```
@Input('array') array: any; - ts

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array | keyvalue"  >
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width"  *ngIf="type(item.value) != 'object'" style="margin-left: 500px; padding-bottom: 50px;" >
  <input matInput placeholder="{{item.key}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value"  name=" " >

</mat-form-field>
  <br>
  <app-iteration-multilingual  style="margin-left: 20px;"  [(array)] = 'item.value' *ngIf="type(item.value) == 'object'"></app-iteration-multilingual>
</ng-container >
```

HTML

---

Comment: Consider clarifying your question , paste more codes about your problem , screenshot of your problem , current result and needed result,
You can use guided way , See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,the syntax to pass input param from parent component to child component is `[inputParam]`

Try this:

```
 <app-iteration-multilingual *ngIf="test" [array] = 'test'></app-iteration-multilingual>
```

Secondly, since you have given the input param name as **array** I am assuming you want to pass an array, but you are passing `'test'` that is a string. If **test** is a variable of type array, bind like this `[array] = test`

Comment: Pass array, not string

Comment: I don't understand you, could you please give me more detailed answear

Comment: the array is and object and this array is just a name from the @Input in the child

Comment: If array is object, it won't work in `ngFor`. `ngFor` works only with arrays

Comment: Can you share a stackbiltz

Comment: and I want to change the data in the object in the first component when In the second one field changes

Comment: the thing is that I have two components in different folders and when data is send from the first on to the second it is iterated and set in inputs values (html). I want when one of this value of the inputs changes, the first input object exact value also changes with the new value. @AdritaSharma

Comment: please if you can help me, help me

Comment: Please recreate and share a stackbiltz link so that I can code the whole thing

Comment: but its is a big project and this part is mine, only this code above I can share you its like it looks like

Comment: If you. know how to binde them

Comment: Here are the two folders, please just add the thing that will bind them like I want

Comment: here is the stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgvtum?file=src%2Fiteration-multilingual%2Fiteration-multilingual.component.ts

Comment: your stackbiltz isn't working. Its showing error `Import error, can't find file:
./app/app.module`. I guess u have forgot to add app.module file

Comment: Also. u haven't added authservice. I understand it is a big project. u can share something that is working with dummy data.. or Can u show the console of `this.tes= await this.authService.getMultilingual('en');` I need to understand what is getting stored in `this.tes`.

Comment: its a json lfile

Comment: for ngx-translate

Comment: That is the issue. It's an object, not an array right? But you are accepting @input of type array

Comment: Since you have added `@Input('array') array: Array<any>;`, you have to pass array, not object. Example of array:  `[{"name":"item 1"},{"name": "item2} ]`, Example of object `{"name": "item1", "description":"a JSON object"}`

Comment: I have no problem with this, everything is visualising perfectly, I want change on of the inputs values the parent array test also changes

Comment: I have another thing, could you pleas tell me how to update the value of the object iterated by ngFor when input value changes, this is in iteration-multilingual component . Want when the value of one onputs changes, the same value of the object array also changes